# Route53 A record not working. Wordpress Website hacked

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I am myself expert on AWS. My website was working fine till yesterday. Suddenly it stopped working. When I debugged; I found that `$ nslookup abc.com`  has stopped giving my A Record ! I double checked on Route 53. Even modified it. All look fine.  Website is working fine if I try using IP address. It is developed using wordpress.

Also, yesterday I got an email saying that my website is hacked and asking for 250 USD as ransom. I would have ignored it as spam but really my website is not working.

Comment: If you do a whois can you validate you still own the domain? Your website likely has not been hacked, either the domain name has expired or someone has maliciously updated your DNS to resolve to their records instead.

Comment: Yes i did confirm it still shows my AWS privacy owner

Comment: OK and the name servers that show on the who is domain?

Comment: nameservers still continue to be AWS route 53

Comment: But they route to your AWS Route 53 nameservers?

Comment: how do i know that !  whois record shows aws nameservers.

Comment: Look at the name servers set in the whois record, compare them to your public hosted zones name servers

Comment: yes nameservers are same. This is like first time happening in my 20 yrs of career. So weird

Comment: I think I found the issue.. Actually domain has expired. AWS does not send any notification etc or even any warning anywhere. Godaddy would send u tons of notification.  Gave renew request; hope it works.

Comment: Glad you identified this, you should be able to contact AWS support if someone else has taken your domain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223156/discussion-between-deepak-singhal-and-chris-williams).

Answer (score 1):

This was one of the weirdest issue. I got so freaked out whole day and not finding any clue how to solve it.

Finally found that root cause was that Domain had expired. AWS Route53 does not send any notification etc or even any warning anywhere. Godaddy would send u tons of notification.

Comment: If your domain is registered with Route 53, you **will** receive multiple notifications about a pending expiration.  I have one that expires in November, auto-renew is disabled, and I began receiving emails about that upcoming expiration back in September.

Comment: surprising i did not receive even a single notification :(  .. So now i made it auto-renew